# Can I change the properties of a binding in a DataTrigger, without knowing the binding itself?

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, styles

I have a `TextBox` style that formats a number if the box is unfocused, but leaves the number unformatted whlie it's being edited.

This is the style I want for multiple number TextBoxes, but they all contain different Text bindings. The only difference between the regular Text setter and the Triggered Text setter is that the Triggered one has `StringFormat=N2` in the binding.

Is there a way I can make this style generic, such as only changing the `StringFormat` property of the binding in the DataTrigger?

```
<TextBox>
    <TextBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding SomeValue, StringFormat=N2, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding SomeValue, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBox.Style>
</TextBox>
```

Comment: I think it isn't possible to change any properties of a binding after it has been applied. At least when i try to change the StringFormat property of an existing binding i get an InvalidOperationException saying `Binding cannot be changed after it has been used.` To me it seems that there is no way around creating a new binding every time the focus changes.

Comment: Thought about this again, and considered some kind of attached `Data` property solution where the property change handler would attach GotFocus/LostFocus handlers etc. In the end i'd prefer to have a derived TextBox with properties `Data` and `StringFormat`, which would set the `Text` property according to their values and the current focus state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only option I see there would be to create an attached property for the StringFormat and use a multiBinding.

Not quite what you wanted, but close enough, I guess...

you have more info on this (kind of duplicate) question on S.O.:

[Modifying the Parameters of a TextBox's Text Binding through the use of a Style](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5594437/479384)

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a way I can make this style generic, such as only changing
>   the StringFormat property of the binding in the DataTrigger?

Inherit `Style` and new XAML would become this:

```
 <TextBox>
    <TextBox.Style>
        <local:FlyingStyle Binding="{Binding ElementName=This, Path=SomeValue}" StringFormat="F2" />
    </TextBox.Style>
 </TextBox>
```

Here's the class...

```
public class FlyingStyle : Style
{
    public FlyingStyle()
        : base(typeof(TextBox))
    { }

    string _stringFormat;
    public string StringFormat
    {
        get { return _stringFormat; }
        set
        {
            _stringFormat = value;
            CheckInitialize();
        }
    }
    Binding _binding;
    public Binding Binding
    {
        get { return _binding; }
        set
        {
            _binding = value;
            CheckInitialize();
        }
    }
    void CheckInitialize()
    {
        if (StringFormat == null || Binding == null) { return; }// need both

        Setters.Add(CreateSetter(Binding, StringFormat));

        var trigger = new Trigger
        {
            Property = UIElement.IsKeyboardFocusWithinProperty,
            Value = true,
        };
        trigger.Setters.Add(CreateSetter(Binding));
        Triggers.Add(trigger);
    }

    /// <summary>Creates the common <see cref="Setter"/>.</summary>
    static Setter CreateSetter(Binding binding, string stringFormat = null)
    {
        // must create a copy, because same binding ref but diff StringFormats
        var bindingCopy = new Binding
        {
            // these could be copies as well
            UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged,
            ValidatesOnDataErrors = true,
            Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay,
            Path = binding.Path,

            AsyncState = binding.AsyncState,
            BindingGroupName = binding.BindingGroupName,
            BindsDirectlyToSource = binding.BindsDirectlyToSource,
            Converter = binding.Converter,
            ConverterCulture = binding.ConverterCulture,
            ConverterParameter = binding.ConverterParameter,
            ElementName = binding.ElementName,
            FallbackValue = binding.FallbackValue,
            IsAsync = binding.IsAsync,
            NotifyOnSourceUpdated = binding.NotifyOnSourceUpdated,
            NotifyOnTargetUpdated = binding.NotifyOnTargetUpdated,
            NotifyOnValidationError = binding.NotifyOnValidationError,
            //StringFormat = set below...
            TargetNullValue = binding.TargetNullValue,
            UpdateSourceExceptionFilter = binding.UpdateSourceExceptionFilter,
            ValidatesOnExceptions = binding.ValidatesOnExceptions,
            XPath = binding.XPath,
            //ValidationRules = binding.ValidationRules
        };
        // mutex ElementName, so modify if needed
        // Source = binding.Source,
        // RelativeSource = binding.RelativeSource,

        if (stringFormat != null)
        {
            bindingCopy.StringFormat = stringFormat;
        }
        return new Setter(TextBox.TextProperty, bindingCopy);
    }
}
```

Note that my test was

- the generic MainWindow
- impl INotifyPropertyChanged
- `SomeValue` INPC property
- DataContext = this
- x:Name = This

Comment: I would prefer to leave my style in the XAML where I can easily access it to make changes to it. This looks like a nightmare to maintain :)

Comment: `This is the style I want for multiple number TextBoxes, but they all contain different Text bindings` made it sound like it's worth the C#. In any event the link in David's answer proposes nearly the same algorithm.

Comment: +1 for a working version, although I prefer the Attached Property shown in David's link since it allows me to keep the rest of my style in the XAML

Answer (score 2):

My attempt to solve this ended up with a custom control plus a multi-binding, both of which where suggested above.

This allowed me to use markup like this:

< CustomTextBox Value="{Binding Value"} Format="N2" />

I tried to post my code but I keep getting an error about "code that is not properly formatted as code".

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering if you could maybe have an attached property on the edits to hold the formatted value (just bound to the real edit value with a Stringformat applied), then in your out of focus trigger you could set the edit value to this property.

This would result in a circular binding though when the edit doesn't have focus, dunno how WPF reacts in such situations.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly this is (to my knowledge) not possible. One possible workaround would be programmatically creating such a style on the fly, that could be encapsulated in a `MarkupExtension` which takes the path as constructor parameter.