# Create a Style for a DataGrid Cell that binds to the underlying data

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, datagrid

Let's assume I have a `WPF` `DataGrid` with this column:

```
<DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding myProperty}" Header="My Property" >
    <DataGridCheckBoxColumn.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding myProperty}" Value="1">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGridCheckBoxColumn.CellStyle>                   
</DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
```

This works as you'd expect: it makes the cell background color `Red` if the underlying value is `1`

To avoid having to write all this for all columns (I have several) I wanted to put the style as a resource, so it could be reused, like this:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell" x:Key="styleCheckboxRed">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="?????" Value="1">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<!-- other stuff... -->

<DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding myProperty}" Header="My Property" CellStyle="{StaticResource styleCheckboxRed}" />
```

But as you can see, I don't know how to set the binding on the DataTrigger to make it work for any generic column... can I somehow reference the Column's own binding? I made various tries with RelativeSource but I don't know the correct approach (if indeed there is one). Any ideas?

Comment: I remember asking a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9129164/302677) a long time back, and there was no easy way of doing this. The common suggestion was to either bind your value to something common like the `Tag` property, and base the trigger off of that, or if no property is available then create an attached property for it. AttachedProperty was usually a little more work, but it made the code easier to read and was clear what the intention was.